# How to drag and drop between different GridViews?

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-gridview

I would like to make an app with 3 `GridView`. The first is to distribute the content to the other `GridView` using drang and drop.

**Problem**: I don't know how to do to exchange the image between the gridViews. I looked for some examples of `GridView`: [DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) , [drag-drop-for-android-gridview](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/), but I couldn't find about exchange the images between the gridViews.

If someone know how to do it, some example or tutorial, help.

Thanks in advance.